# Combine multiple sphinx documentation sites

Tags: python-sphinx, searchable

I would like to combine multiple sphinx generated documentation sites into a single location (site). I dont want to replicate the work, but just want to index/search it from a central location.

**Requirements**:

1. Searchable documentation across all sites from main site
2. Searched link takes you to target site/location
3. Link to all other sites (should be easy enough)

**MainSite**

- Site 1
- Site 2
- Site n

I was thinking of somehow combining the index databases from the various sites, but did not know if that was possible.  I am finding very little information about doing this.

I had considered using a google search that specifically targets the desired sites, but would like to keep the Sphinx look and ease of use. Is this even possible? Any ideas how?
Thanks

Comment: intersphinx may do the job: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/intersphinx.html